# Long and rotated table

Tags: longtable, rotating, landscape, adjustbox, sidewaystable

[image]I'm trying to make a table over multiple pages (longtable) and over the width of the page. Is there a way to combine these two? I tried sideaystable, adjustbox and landscape, but they do not seem compatible with a longtable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[h]
\centering
\caption{Post-combustion CCS technologies}
\label{tab:CCS}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\toprule
Technology & Principle & Advantages & Disadvantages  \\
\toprule
Absorption          & CO\textsubscript{2} is contacted with a solvent & Commercially available & High CAPEX, OPEX, efficiency losses \\
or (chemical) scrubbing & in a packed column, counter flow            & Assumed to be mature   & due to energy demand for regeneration\\
                & Solvent sorbs more soluble CO\textsubscript{2}  & Know-how from industry & Transferable to power plants?\\
                & over other compounds in flue gas                & e.g. acid gas removal, & Accumulation of trace compounds \\ 
                & Purer CO\textsubscript{2} released in regeneration & CO\textsubscript{2} removal in IGCC  & Foaming: reduces absorption efficiency \\ 
                & Solvent: amines, alkaline earth                 & Low consumables demand & Environmental impact of solvents: \\
                & solutions, glycol, ammonia, water               & Solvent regeneration   & (eco)toxicity and corrosion\\ %Add half midrule?
                & Upcoming: aqueous ammonia                       & High CO\textsubscript{2} capacity & Volatile \\
                &                                                 & Lower heat demand, lower OPEX & Cooling of flue gas to 15-30\textdegree C needed \\
                &                                                 & Small make-up demand:  & to minimise solvent emission\\
                &                                                 & tolerance to O\textsubscript{2} & \\
                &                                                 & Potential for simultaneous SO\textsubscript{x}, NO\textsubscript{x} removal by forming ammonia sulphate and nitrate (can be sold as fertilisers) & \\
                & Ionic liquids: salt of                          & Stable up 100s\textdegree C: & Very expensive chemicals (new)\\
                & organic cation +                                & no cooling of flue gas needed & High viscosity: \\
                & (in)organic anion                               & Small energy demand for regeneration & unpractical \\
                & Physical solvent for CO\textsubscript{2}        & (physical sorption)    & \\
                & Solubility depends on anion                     & Simultaneous SO\textsubscript{x} removal & \\
\midrule 
Adsorption          & CO\textsubscript{2} is contacted with a adsorbent & Simple concept,       & Purifying steps complicate process \\
                & in a bed reactor                                  & low CAPEX             & Rather impure by-product \\
                & Preferential adsorption of CO\textsubscript{2}    & Regeneration by tempe-& Not for too strongly binding species \\
                & Physisorption: Van der Waals                      & rature and pressure   &  \\
                & forces between surface of adsorbent               & swing adsorption      &  \\
                & and CO\textsubscript{2}.                          & (TSA, PSA) \nomenclature{TSA}{Temperature swing adsorption} \nomenclature{PSA}{Pressure swing adsorption} at lower &  \\  
                & Chemisorption: interaction between                & cost and energy       &  \\
                & functional groups of the adsorbate                & demand than for       &  \\ 
                & and CO\textsubscript{2} to form weak bonds.       & absorption, low OPEX  &   \\
                & e.g. clays, zeolites, activated carbon,           & Tunable affinity of   &   \\
                & carbon nanotubes, metal-organic                   & organics: addition of &   \\
                & frameworks (MOFs) & functional groups&   \\
                & CO\textsubscript{2} adsorption potential depends  & e.g. nitrogenous groups&   \\
                & on functional groups, porosity,                   & or metal oxides       &  \\
                & surface area, pore size, metal ligands            & High permeate purity, &  \\
                & and electrostatic interactions.                   & possibly with extra steps&  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I suppose  you mean over the *height* of the page, since you mention rotated text. Normally longtable and landscape are compatible.

Comment: welcome to tex.se!  do you need `landscape` oriented table?`longtable` is compatible(only) with `landscape` environment, it doesn't work with `sidewaystable` (since it is limited only to one page). use `adjustbox` only  in desperate measure of the last resort ... for more, provide small but complete document with your table.

Comment: A landscape oriented longtable would be perfect.
Also, is there a package that makes the table fit the page width automatically?

Comment: the `landscape` environment of the (pdf)lscape package was specifically written for `longtable` why do you say they are not compatible?  also longtable does not have an `[h]` option.

Comment: your longtable can not break over a page as it only has one column and one row, containing a `tabular`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't understand the one row and one column.
I deleted the [h], but no improvement.
I added a prtsc in my original question.

Comment: `longtable` requires a column specification eg `{lllll}` like tabular but you have not got one so you will have errors at that point. and you should have no `tabular` environment at all. search this site or the longtable documentation there are literally thousands of longtable examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your table has to many issues that can be solved in one step, also your document example is not complete and consequently is not compilable.

first off-topic comments:

- it contains chem formulas. why you not use `mchem` packages and write for example `\ce{CO2}` instead `CO\textsubscript{2}`
- it is very recommendable to use the package `siunitx` for all units. for example `\SIrange{15}{30}{\celsius}` instead `15 -- 30 \textdegree C`
- it seems that you break text between rows instead to use multi line cells (like `p{...}` or `X` if you use packages `tabularx` or `ltablex`) where is collected text, i e. your table actually has only two rows ...

on-topic:

- i try to rewrite your table, however i went to lost in your text. so the correct text in cells i left to you
- columns you can define in `longtable`

an example, how you can rewrite your table (of course with coorrect contents in cells):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.19\linewidth} *{3}{p{0.27\linewidth}|} }
\caption{Post-combustion CCS technologies}
\label{tab:CCS}  \\
\toprule
Technology & Principle & Advantages & Disadvantages  \\
\toprule
Absorption or (chemical) scrubbing
    & \ce{CO2} is contacted with a solvent in a packed column, counter flow over other compounds in flue gas
        & Commercially available
            & High CAPEX, OPEX, efficiency losses due to energy demand for regeneration \\
    &   & Assumed to be mature
            & \\
    & Solvent sorbs more soluble \ce{CO2}
        & Know-how from industry e.g. acid gas removal,
            & Transferable to power plants?\\
    &
        &
            & Accumulation of trace compounds \\
    & Purer \ce{CO2} released in regeneration
        & \ce{CO2} removal in IGCC
            & Foaming: reduces absorption efficiency \\
    & Solvent: amines, alkaline earth
        & Low consumables demand & Environmental impact of solvents: \\
            & solutions, glycol, ammonia, water
                & Solvent regeneration   & (eco)toxicity and corrosion\\
    %Add half midrule?
    & Upcoming: aqueous ammonia
        & High \ce{CO2} capacity & Volatile \\
    &
        & Lower heat demand, lower OPEX & Cooling of flue gas to \SIrange{15}{30}{\celsius} needed \\
    &
        & Small make-up demand:
            & to minimise solvent emission\\
    &
        & tolerance to \ce{O2}
            & \\
    &
        & Potential for simultaneous SO\textsubscript{x}, \ce{NOx} removal by forming ammonia sulphate and nitrate (can be sold as fertilisers)
            & \\
    & Ionic liquids: salt of
        & Stable up \SI{100}{\celsius}:
            & Very expensive chemicals (new)\\
    & organic cation + (in)organic anion
        & no cooling of flue gas needed (physical sorption)
            & High viscosity: unpractical \\
    &
        & Small energy demand for regeneration
            & \\
    & Physical solvent for \ce{CO2}
        &
            & \\
    & Solubility depends on anion
        & Simultaneous SO\textsubscript{x} removal
            & \\
\midrule
Adsorption
    & \ce{CO2} is contacted with a adsorbent in a bed reactor
        & Simple concept, low CAPEX
            & Purifying steps complicate process

              Rather impure by-product
              Not for too strongly binding species \\
    & Preferential adsorption of \ce{CO2}
        & Regeneration by temperature and pressure swing adsorption and \ce{CO2}.
            & \\
    & Physisorption: Van der Waals forces between surface of adsorbent e.g. clays, zeolites, activated carbon, carbon nanotubes, metal-organic frameworks (MOFs)
        &
            &  \\
    &
        & (TSA, PSA) %\nomenclature{TSA}{Temperature swing adsorption} \nomenclature{PSA}{Pressure swing adsorption}
                at lower cost and energy absorption, low OPEX demand than for
            &  \\
    & Chemisorption: interaction between functional groups of the adsorbate and \ce{CO2} to form weak bonds.
        &
            &  \\
    &
        & Tunable affinity of
            &   \\
    &
        & organics: addition of functional groups on functional groups, porosity, surface area, pore size, metal ligands and electrostatic interactions.
            &   \\
    & \ce{CO2} adsorption potential depends
        & e.g. nitrogenous groups or metal oxides
            &   \\
    &
        & High permeate purity, possibly with extra steps
            &  \\
\midrule
Cryogenic distillation & Preferred condensation of CO\textsubscript{2}  &  & Very low temperatures: \\
\cite{Creamer, CCSbook, Bauer2013} & over other gases (N\textsubscript{2}, CH\textsubscript{4})&  & high energy demand, \\
                   & based on differences in vapour pressures and volatilities &  & high OPEX, efficiency losses \\
                   & Outcoming CO\textsubscript{2} is liquid  &  & Prior H\textsubscript{2}O removal needed \\
                   & More used for air separation in oxyfuel combustion        &  & \\
                   & Share of 0.5\% in biogas upgrading market                 &  & \\
\midrule
Carbonate looping      & Dry sorption of CO\textsubscript{2} on metallic oxides in carbonater & High purity& Efficiency losses (7.2\%) \\
              & Desorption under temperature or pressure swing in calcinator & Endothermic: released heat usable in power plants & Lab scale  \\
              & Dual fluidised bed reactor & Smaller efficiency loss in regeneration compared to amine sorption &   \\
              & or fixed bed in one reactor& Assumed to be retrofittable &   \\
              & & &   \\
              & & &   \\
              & e.g. CaO, lithium silicates & &   \\
\midrule    
Enzyme-based systems & Based on natural CO\textsubscript{2} capture & Enhanced mass transfer and CO\textsubscript{2}: & \\
                 & by living organisms                          & less hindrance of aqueous CO2 hydratation rate and buffering capacity &   \\
                 & Enzymes, carbonic anhydrase                  & Smaller energy penalty: & Limited by membrane boundary layers, \\
                 & immobilised on gas/liquid interphase         & very low heat of absorption, &pore wetting, surface fouling \\
                 & of hollow fiber liquid membrane:             & regeneration at ambient conditions & and loss of enzyme activity  \\
                 & imitating mammal respiration                 & Limited amount of enzyme needed, & Lab scale: long-term \\
                 & Enzyme increases carbonic                    & small make-up demand: & operation tests and scaling up needed\\
                 & acid formation rate                          & due to the fast turn-over rate&   \\
                 & of water scrubbing                           & &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

**addendum (edited):**
in case that you like to have `\onehalfspace` in the main text and in table spacing for example 1.1 space, than in preamble add

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspace
```

and after `\begin{landscape}` add `\setstretch{1.1}`. both are now considered in *mwe* below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{enumitem}        % for nice list
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     topsep     = 0pt       ,
                     partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                     leftmargin = *         ,
                     label      = $\bullet$ ,
                     before     = \vspace{\baselineskip},
                     after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{setspace}   % added in edit
\onehalfspace           % added in edit
\usepackage{lipsum}     % added in edit

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]            % added in edit
\begin{landscape}
\setstretch{1.1}        % added in edit
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{15ex}
            X X X @{}}
\caption{Post-combustion CCS technologies}
\label{tab:CCS}  \\
    \toprule
Technology & Principle & Advantages & Disadvantages  \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Post-combustion CCS technologies (cont.)}
\label{tab:CCS}  \\
    \toprule
Technology & Principle & Advantages & Disadvantages  \\
    \midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Absorption or (chemical) scrubbing
    &   \begin{tabitem}
        \item   \ce{CO2} is contacted with a solvent in a packed column, counter flow over other compounds in flue gas
        \item   Solvent sorbs more soluble \ce{CO2}
        \item   Purer \ce{CO2} released in regeneration
        \item  Solvent: amines, alkaline earth solutions, glycol, ammonia, water
        \end{tabitem}
        &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item   Commercially available
            \item   Assumed to be mature
            \item   Know-how from industry e.g. acid gas removal
            \item   \ce{CO2} removal in IGCC
            \item   Low consumables demand
            \item   Solvent regeneration
            \end{tabitem}
            &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   High CAPEX, OPEX, efficiency losses due to energy demand for regeneration
                \item   Transferable to power plants?
                \item   Accumulation of trace compounds
                \item   Foaming: reduces absorption efficiency
                \item   Environmental impact of solvents: (eco)toxicity and corrosion
                \end{tabitem}                           \\
    \addlinespace
    &   Upcoming: aqueous ammonia
        &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item   High \ce{CO2} capacity
            \item   Lower heat demand, lower OPEX
            \item   Small make-up demand: tolerance to \ce{O2}
            \item   Potential for simultaneous SO\textsubscript{x}, \ce{NOx} removal by forming ammonia sulphate and nitrate (can be sold as fertilisers)
            \end{tabitem}
            &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   Volatile
                \item   Cooling of flue gas to \SIrange{15}{30}{\celsius} needed to minimise solvent emission
                \end{tabitem}                           \\
    \addlinespace
    &   Ionic liquids: salt of organic cation + (in)organic anion
        \bigskip
        &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item   Stable up \SI{100}{\celsius}: no cooling of flue gas needed (physical sorption)
            \item   Small energy demand for regeneration
            \end{tabitem}
            &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   Very expensive chemicals (new)
                \item   High viscosity: unpractical
                \end{tabitem}                           \\
    \addlinespace
    &   Physical solvent for \ce{CO2}
        \bigskip
        \begin{tabitem}
        \item   Solubility depends on anion
        \end{tabitem}
           &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   Simultaneous SO\textsubscript{x} removal
                \end{tabitem}                           \\
\midrule
Adsorption
    &   \begin{tabitem}
        \item   \ce{CO2} is contacted with a adsorbent in a bed reactor
        \item   Preferential adsorption of \ce{CO2}
        \item   Physisorption: Van der Waals forces between surface of adsorbent e.g. clays, zeolites, activated carbon, carbon nanotubes, metal-organic frameworks (MOFs)
        \item   Chemisorption: interaction between functional groups of the adsorbate and \ce{CO2} to form weak bonds.
        \item   \ce{CO2} adsorption potential depends
        \end{tabitem}
        &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item   Simple concept, low CAPEX
            \item   Regeneration by temperature and pressure swing adsorption and \ce{CO2}.
            \item   (TSA, PSA) %\nomenclature{TSA}{Temperature swing adsorption} \nomenclature{PSA}{Pressure swing adsorption}
                at lower cost and energy absorption, low OPEX demand than for ?
            \item   Tunable affinity of organics: addition of functional groups on functional groups, porosity, surface area, pore size, metal ligands and electrostatic interactions.
            \item   e.g. nitrogenous groups or metal oxides
            \item   High permeate purity, possibly with extra steps
            \end{tabitem}
           &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   Purifying steps complicate process
                \item   Rather impure by-product
                \item   Not for too strongly binding species
                \end{tabitem}                           \\
    \midrule
Cryogenic distillation
\cite{Creamer, CCSbook, Bauer2013}
    &   \begin{tabitem}
        \item   Preferred condensation of \ce{CO2} over other gases (\ce{N2}, \ce{CH4}) based on differences in vapour pressures and volatilities
        \item   Outcoming \ce{CO2} is liquid
        \item   More used for air separation in oxyfuel combustion
        \item   Share of \SI{0.5}{\%} in biogas upgrading market
        \end{tabitem}
        &   &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   Very low temperatures
                \item   high energy demand
                \item   high OPEX, efficiency losses
                \item   Prior \ce{H2O} removal needed
                \end{tabitem}   \\
    \midrule
Carbonate looping
    &   \begin{tabitem}
        \item   Dry sorption of \ce{CO2} on metallic oxides in carbonater
        \item   Desorption under temperature or pressure swing in calcinator
        \item   Dual fluidised bed reactor or fixed bed in one reactor e.g. \ce{CaO}, lithium silicates
        \end{tabitem}
        &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item   High purity
            \item   Endothermic: released heat usable in power plants
            \item   Smaller efficiency loss in regeneration compared to amine sorption
            \item   Assumed to be retrofittable
            \end{tabitem}
            &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   Efficiency losses (\SI{7.2}{\%})
                \item   Lab scale
                \end{tabitem}                               \\
    \midrule
Enzyme-based systems
    &   \begin{tabitem}
        \item   Based on natural CO\textsubscript{2} capture by living organisms
        \item   Enzymes, carbonic anhydrase immobilised on gas/liquid interphase of hollow fiber liquid membrane: imitating mammal respiration
        \item   Enzyme increases carbonic acid formation rate of water scrubbing
        \end{tabitem}
        &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item   Enhanced mass transfer and CO\textsubscript{2}: less hindrance of aqueous CO2 hydratation rate and buffering capacity
            \item   Smaller energy penalty: very low heat of absorption regeneration at ambient conditions
            \item   Limited by membrane boundary layers, small make-up demand: due to the fast turn-over rate
            \end{tabitem}
            &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   Limited amount of enzyme needed, pore wetting, surface fouling and loss of enzyme activity
                \item   Lab scale: long-term operation tests and scaling up needed
                \end{tabitem}                           \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(shown are only first page from three, table consider changes introduced by editing of answer)

Comment: That looks like the table I need. I'm trying it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: The file won't compile anymore. Even when I comment out all other chapters and try the fast [draft] compile

Comment: @Lore, you change something ... what is error? in first step write correct content to cell in my answer. when this will work, than move table to your document.

Comment: "Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run ...
So I tried to do only recompile this chapter by commenting the others away in my main document and I tried the fast [draft] recompilation, but still nothing

Comment: When I don't load the chapter with this table, it does work.

Comment: Everything works again and it looks really good. Thank you so much!

Comment: I had to change the interline space of my text to 1.5 and it also applied this to the table. How can I keep the table to interline something more like 1-1.15? And maybe fondsize 10-11?

Comment: if you use the packae `setspace` for this, than put in preamble `\onehalfspace` and in the `landscape` environment for example `\setstretch{1.1}`. see edited answer.

Comment: It doesn't recognise the [\onehalfspace] and \setstretch{1.1} commands even though I load \usepackage{setspace}. Could it be due to the document class: \documentclass[master=eelt,masteroption=ei]{kulemt} ?

Comment: @Lore, my mwe works. result i show in answer. if your document class `kulemt` (which i haven't), has some features, as are line spread in text, hard coded, i don't know. sorry, in this i can't help you.

Comment: that's ok. I had to put it in appendices so it won't matter that much. That you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a code made with Tabu, only to prove that **longtabu works in the environment of pdfscape** which is one of the things I wanted to solve; the example has some of the multiple options implemented for modifying tabu text, headers and table footings waiting to be used and an improvised manual mode (brute force) of placing notes in the table, I think there is a packet tenominated threeparttable, but I think which is not compatible with the longtable environment ... **I do not know if the online compiler has enough power to compile everything**, or if it has a good error handling, I use **TeXstudio** with **MiKTeX** and the Arara automation, which has implemented bug detection and it helps me a lot to make compatible codes and packages.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry} %set quickly page dimmensions

\usepackage{tabu} %for beauty tables
\usepackage{longtable} %needed for longtabu
\usepackage{tabularx} %
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows the definition of hex colors
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} % to rotate page to prevent stiff neck...
\usepackage{siunitx} % To put easily SI units.
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % To put some dummy text.
\definecolor{tabu}{HTML}{002fa7} %define colar named tabu in HTML
\newcommand{\cmt}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}% \superscript is too long ro rewrite many times

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1-4]    
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{small}
            \tabulinesep = 2mm
            \tabulinestyle{1pt tabu}
            \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {X[.7l]X[2]X[2]X[2]} %X[ab]: X-type of column,a-widht factor,b-align.  
                % Define the end foot.
                %\tabucline -  uncoment if you do manually references. 
                \multicolumn{4}{l}{\sc\scriptsize\color{tabu}Continues in the next page\ldots}\\ \endfoot
                %define the end last foot.
                \endlastfoot % its necesary if you need 
                %define the header
                \caption{Post-combustion CCS technologies} \label{tab:CCS}   \\
                \tabucline -
                \rowfont[c]{\bf \color{blue}} % To formating all the row elements.
                Technology & Principle & Advantages & Disadvantages  \\ \tabucline - \endhead
                %table body.
                    \bf Absorption or (chermical) scrubing %File 1 column 1 bold
                    & \ce{CO2} is contacted with a solvent  in a packed column, counter flow Solvent sorbs more soluble \ce{CO2} Solvent sorbs more soluble \ce{CO2} over other compounds in flue gas Purer \ce{CO2} released in regeneration Solvent: amines, alkaline earth solutions, glycol, ammonia, water     %File 1 column 2
                    & Commercially available Assumed to be mature Know-how from industry e.g. acid gas removal, \ce{CO2} removal in IGCC Low consumables demand Solvent regeneration (TSA\cmt{1}, PSA\cmt{2}) %File 1 column 3
                    & High CAPEX, OPEX, efficiency losses due to energy demand for regeneration Transferable to power plants? Accumulation of trace compounds Foaming: reduces absorption efficiency Environmental impact of solvents: (eco)toxicity and corrosion \\ %End File 1 column 4 
                    Lost in chemistry %File 2 column 1
                    & \bf \lipsum[5] %File 2 column 2 text bold.
                    & \cellcolor{blue} \color{white} \vspace{-.5\baselineskip} \sf \lipsum[4] %File 2 column 3
                    & \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}\color{blue} \lipsum[3] \\ \tabucline -%End File 2 column 4, text colo blue with correction in vertical space.
                    %Manually reference: by brute force.
                    \multicolumn{4}{p{15cm}}{\scriptsize  %multicolumn whit paragraph mode its mandatory toindicate the width.
                        1\, {\bf TSA}:\,Temperature swing adsorption. \par
                        2\, {\bf PSA}:\,Pressure swing adsorption.
                    }\\ 
                    I'm still lost. %File 3 column 1
                    & \lipsum[1] %File 3 column 2
                    &  \vspace{-\baselineskip} % to correct the default spacing from itemize environment.
                        \begin{itemize}
                        \item High CAPEX\cmt{3} /, OPEX\cmt{4}, efficiency losses due to energy
                        \item \ce{CO2} is contacted with a solvent  in a packed column, counter flow Solvent sorbs more soluble \ce{CO2} .
                        \item Commercially available Assumed to be mature. 
                        \end{itemize} %File 3 column 3 witth environment itemize.
                    & \lipsum[7] \\ \tabucline - %End File 3 column 4
                    %Manually reference: by brute force 2.
                    \multicolumn{4}{p{15cm}}{\scriptsize  %multicolumn whit paragraph mode its mandatory toindicate the width.
                        3\, {\bf CAPEX}:\,Something that I dont know \par %\, is an spacing command
                        4\, {\bf OPEX}:\, Maybe something related.
                    }\\ 

            \end{longtabu}
        \end{small}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

This is the result. (The dimensions of the sheets are modified to make the image compact and with the necessary resolution so that the details can be seen)

[image]